# Wrong Link Text in Django App

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm messing around with Django for the first time here and I've got some preliminary stuff set up. On the admin page, I have a custom app with database functionality that is working correctly. However, the link text is incorrect (highlighted in red [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fna2S.png)). It should just say "Recipes" without the second "s." I can't figure out why this happened or how to fix it. Here's the code from some key files that I've already checked.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'recipes',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Recipes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ingredients = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name + " / " + self.ingredients
```

admin.py

```
from recipes.models import Recipes  
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Recipes)
```

For the record, my folder for this app is also named "recipes".

How can I fix this link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some Meta information. `verbose_name`, by default would have the model name, and `verbose_name_plural`, by default would have an `s` appended to the `verbose_name`. You need to override that.

```
class Recipes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ingredients = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name + " / " + self.ingredients

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Recipe"
        verbose_name_plural = "Recipies"
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual convention is to use singular nouns as your model name - `Recipe` rather than `Recipes`.

If you really want to use `Recipes` as the model name, you can customize the displayed names using the `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural` attributes on your model's `Meta` class as documented here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#verbose-name